# Актуальный способ подключить скрипт с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Вот, надо подключить скрипт по событию onclick

Answer (score 3):

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = function () {

};
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";
head.insertBefore(script, head.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]);
```